# Can I use a PHP (laravel) controller directly inside my VueJS view?

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I added a searchbar with results with VueJS, and this works great with a simple query. Now, I would like to do the same but with more complex filters.

Here is my VueJS search component

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @click="search" @keyup.enter="search" type="button">Search</button>

methods: {
            search() {
                axios.get('/races/find?q=%'+ this.query+'%').then(
                    response => {
                        this.races=response.data;
                    }
                );
            }
        }
```

in web.php

```
Route::get('/race/find', 'RacesController@searchRaces');
```

in RacesController

```
public function searchRaces(Request $request)
{
    return DB::connection('mysql1')->select(REQUEST);
}
```

This works great.

Now I will have some more complex filters, with dates, sliders, multiple data. So i can't pass it directly in my query, or I would have a super long request with 15 values...
Is it possible to call directly my Laravel controller in  my Vue view?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Controller's methods need to be called via HTTP. Complex filters, like dates, etc. are typical, so don't worry about it. Change you query to post, and assign data to it:

```js
search() {
    let filters = {
        query: this.query,
        date: this.date,
        // ...
    };
    axios.post('/races/find', filters).then(
        response => {
            this.races=response.data;
        }
    );
}
```

routes in web.php:

```php
Route::post('/race/find', 'RacesController@searchRaces');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i guess my brain was stuck somewhere :$